# Color Picker Combo Box

Tags: combobox, custom-controls, customization

I want to customize my combobox each item, same as font, background, etc.

Is there any simple way to set custom background color of each Combobox item?

Comment: The question is a bit old, but for someone who still looks for the feature, you can take a look at this post: [Show list of colors in ComboBox - Color Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59009924/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example to do that. In this example my combobox has some item same as color name (Red, Blue, etc) and change the background of each item from this. Just flow the steps:


1) Set the **DrawMode** to **OwnerDrawVariable**:

If this property set to **Normal** this control never raise DrawItem event

```
ComboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
```

2) Add an **DrawItem** event:

```
ComboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBox1_DrawItem);
```

3) Entry your own code to customize each item:

```
private void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics g = e.Graphics;
   Rectangle rect = e.Bounds; //Rectangle of item
   if (e.Index >= 0)
   {
      //Get item color name
      string itemName = ((ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();

      //Get instance a font to draw item name with this style
      Font itemFont = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular);

      //Get instance color from item name
      Color itemColor = Color.FromName(itemName);

      //Get instance brush with Solid style to draw background
      Brush brush = new SolidBrush(itemColor);

      //Draw the item name
      g.DrawString(itemName, itemFont, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Top);

      //Draw the background with my brush style and rectangle of item
      g.FillRectangle(brush, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
   }
}
```

4) Colors need to be added as well:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Black");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Blue");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Lime");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Cyan");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Red");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Fuchsia");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Yellow");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("White");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Navy");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Green");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Teal");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Maroon");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Purple");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Olive");
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Gray");
```

You can change the rectangle size and position to draw your own item as you want.

I hope this post is useful.