# How to set the selection of a combobox from a numeric value to a named color

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I created a color picker combobox from some code I found on this site, although I can not find the code now.

Code to draw the colors:

```
Private Sub cboColorPicker_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboColor.DrawItem, cboBackground.DrawItem

    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim ItemBrush As Brush
    Dim ItemColor As Color
    Dim ItemFont As Font
    Dim ItemName As String
    Dim rect As Rectangle


    g = e.Graphics
    rect = e.Bounds

    If e.Index >= 0 Then
        'Get item color name
        ItemName = CType(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString

        'Get instance a font to draw item name with this style
        ItemFont = New Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Regular)

        'Get instance color from item name
        ItemColor = Color.FromName(ItemName)

        'Get instance brush with Solid style to draw background
        ItemBrush = New SolidBrush(ItemColor)

        'Draw the item name
        g.DrawString(ItemName, ItemFont, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Top)

        'Draw the background with my brush style and rectangle of item
        g.FillRectangle(ItemBrush, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height)

    End If

End Sub
```

I populate the combobox like this:

```
Private Sub PopulateColorCombo(ByVal cbo As ComboBox)

    cbo.Items.Add("Black")
    cbo.Items.Add("Blue")
    cbo.Items.Add("Lime")
    cbo.Items.Add("Cyan")
    cbo.Items.Add("Red")
    cbo.Items.Add("Fuchsia")
    cbo.Items.Add("Yellow")
    cbo.Items.Add("White")
    cbo.Items.Add("Navy")
    cbo.Items.Add("Green")
    cbo.Items.Add("Teal")
    cbo.Items.Add("Maroon")
    cbo.Items.Add("Purple")
    cbo.Items.Add("Olive")
    cbo.Items.Add("Gray")

End Sub
```

I store the value in the database as an int, for example black will be -16777216.

This is part of a form that allows the user to customize a report.  I would like to update the combo when data is loaded to show the color based on what has been stored in the database.  I can not seem to do this.

So say the data I load as HDI.Color = -16777216

```
Color.FromArgb(HDI.Color).ToString = "Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=0]"
Color.FromArgb(HDI.Color).Name = "ff000000"
```

But I can not get the actual color name.  None of the following work.

```
cboColor.SelectedIndex = cboColor.FindStringExact(Color.FromArgb(HDI.Color).ToKnownColor.ToString)
cboColor.SelectedIndex = cboColor.FindStringExact(CType(Color.FromArgb(HDI.Color), Color).ToString)
cboColor.SelectedIndex = cboColor.FindStringExact(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Color.FromArgb(HDI.Color).Name).ToString)
```

Am I using the wrong combobox for this task?  Is there a way to make it work?

I didn't want to offer a full color picker because they will not use many colors so I was trying to keep it simple for the users.  I may even reduce the colors by half.

EDIT: Fix the leaking issues.

Private Sub cboColorPicker_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cboColor.DrawItem, cboBackground.DrawItem

```
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim ItemColor As Color
    Dim ItemName As String
    Dim rect As Rectangle


    g = e.Graphics
    rect = e.Bounds

    If e.Index >= 0 Then
        'Get item color name
        ItemName = CType(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString

        'Get instance color from item name
        ItemColor = Color.FromName(ItemName)

        'Get instance brush with Solid style to draw background
        Using ItemBrush = New SolidBrush(ItemColor)

            'Draw the item name
            g.DrawString(ItemName, DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Font, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Top)

            'Draw the background with my brush style and rectangle of item
            g.FillRectangle(ItemBrush, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height)

        End Using

    End If

End Sub
```

Table Structure:
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you got the code from [Color Picker Combo Box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25616698/719186).  You're adding "strings" to your combobox, so I would think you would just store the "string" in your database.

Comment: Your code is leaking.  You dont need a new Font for each item. Set the cbo to the desired font and use that.  Also the brush ought be disposed

Comment: Instead of storing the `Color.ToArgb` value in the database, store the KnownColor enum value.  That way you can recreate the KnownColor and access its name.

Comment: @LarsTech - You are correct that is where I got it from.  That type of change would require changing a half dozen tables, half dozen objects and the report writer.  Maybe I'll just wait to see if anyone actually needs any color before I make all those modifications, unless you have any other ideas.

Comment: @Plutonix - Thats too bad, I'll fix it but I suspect others will have the same bad code seeing as I got it from the link where Lars pointed it out.

Comment: @TnTinMn - Thats a big job since the header, column headers, datatables, subreports, sections and footers all have color options.  That would mean all the tables and associated objects would need to be changed.  Maybe I'll wait until someone complains it does not work.  They may never notice.

Comment: Just because it is from here doesnt give it any special quality guarantee. It hasnt been able to garner any upvotes in 3 years which says something about it

Comment: "That would mean all the tables and associated objects would need to be changed." -- I do not understand your logic as no changes to the DB structure would be required.  You are currently storing an Integer value and the KnownColor enum value is an Integer value.  Or are you saying that there is a large amount of existing data that would require conversion?  There are other options to convert an ARGB integer to a KnownColor, but if this project is in the design phase, it makes sense to avoid unneeded data manipulation.

Comment: @TnTinMn - This project is in the design phase, but the report isn't.  It is a very large report which requires almost 20 SQL statements.  All the report characteristics have been stored in the database.  My main focus was to get the printer object working and the right data back.  I didn't expect the UI to require major changes.  Might not be so bad though since I only use black and gray.  Glad you pointed out the Known color was just an enum so no table changes, just data.  I'll have to go over the data when I get a chance.  I'll also check for alternate color pickers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it, here is the solution:

```
    Dim ActualColor As Color
    Dim ColorToCheck As KnownColor


    For Each ColorToCheck In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor))
        ActualColor = Color.FromKnownColor(ColorToCheck)
        If Not ActualColor.IsSystemColor And HDI.Color = ActualColor.ToArgb Then
            cboColor.Text = ActualColor.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```