# Show list of colors in ComboBox - Color Picker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I'd like to fill my `ComboBox` with a list of all colors. I was expecting Something like:

```
CBcolor.DataSource = AllColor;
```

Then I'd like to use my ComboBox like this:

```
Color selected = CBcolor.selectedvalue;   
C_ObjetGraphique cercle = new dessin.Cercle(e.Location, selected, selected, 100);
cercle.Affiche();
ledessin.ajoute(cercle);
```

How can I Show list of colors in my `ComboBox` as a color picker?

Comment: how about: var myColors = new List<Color>(); for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) myColors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i)). you can also use the colors from System.Drawing.SystemColors.

Comment: Can you explicitly tell us the platform/technology you are using (WinForms, WPF, WebForms...) and the Colors class (is it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.colors?view=netframework-4.8, or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netframework-4.8, or something else...)

Comment: hello, yep sorry, i'm on WinForm, on the top i writted :using System.Drawing;

Comment: Are you looking for a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.colordialog?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: string[] colorStrs = typeof(Color).GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color)).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();

Comment: Omg thanks you so much, you can post it as answer to make it "solved"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general you need to set the list of colors as data source of combo box. You may have a list of some predefined colors like Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue; You may rely on `KnownColor`, or you may use reflection to get `Color` properties of `Color` type.

In this example I use color properties of the `Color` type to show a combo box like this:

[image: Show List of Colors in ComboBox]

Get list of colors and set data source of combo box:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = typeof(Color).GetProperties()
    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(Color))
    .Select(x => x.GetValue(null)).ToList();
```

Handle custom draw of the combo box:

```
comboBox1.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
comboBox1.IntegralHeight = false;
comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox1.DrawItem += comboBox1_DrawItem;
```

Then for `comboBox1_DrawItem`:

```
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        var txt = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[e.Index]);
        var color = (Color)comboBox1.Items[e.Index];
        var r1 = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 1, e.Bounds.Top + 1,
            2 * (e.Bounds.Height - 2), e.Bounds.Height - 2);
        var r2 = Rectangle.FromLTRB(r1.Right + 2, e.Bounds.Top,
            e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom);
        using (var b = new SolidBrush(color))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, r1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r1);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, comboBox1.Font, r2,
            comboBox1.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }
}
```

Get the selected color from combo box:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex>=0)
    this.BackColor = (Color)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```