# How can I colour the lines in a combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, combobox

I want to colour different lines in a combobox. I know how I can ajust the text colour of all the lines, but not how to ajust indivdual lines.

```
foreach (bool Is_Aligned in Selected_Class.Allowed_Alignment)
{
    if (!Is_Aligned) Alignment_Selection.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    else Alignment_Selection.ForeColor = Color.Green;

    Alignment_Selection.Items.Add(Build.Alignment.Alignment_List[i]);

    i++;
}
```

I was hoping that by adjusting the colour each time I add an item to the combobox the newly added line would be the colour chosen when added, but all lines are the colour of the last line.

Edit:
I'm trying to do this in Visual Studio, C# Win Forms Apps

Comment: Is this WinForms? WPF? Something else? Please provide all relevant tags and the technology being used is always relevant.

Comment: [ComboBox.DrawItem Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77352166/how-can-i-colour-the-lines-in-a-combobox#77352166) (Edited to fix link) - Weird, the link keeps getting modified to point to this comment??? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: I hopefully added the necessary information to the post, which I'll repeat here: I'm trying to do this in Visual Studio, C# Win Forms Apps

Comment: Might be a [good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59007745/1997232).