# Set a Different Color to Each Item in ComboBox (C#)

Tags: c#, colors, datagridview, combobox

I'm writing code in C# (in Visual Studio, to be precise), and I want to create a DataGridView with a column of ComboBoxes, such that each ComboBox allows the user to select a color (from an existing list). I would like each color-name in the ComboBox to be the same color as the color-name implies (i.e. the color-name "Red" will appear red in the ComboBox when it's opene, and so on).

I saw people using the DrawItem event for regular ComboBoxes to do that, but I'm not sure how to do the same for a DataGridViewComboBoxCell (I've added the ComboBoxes to the DataGridView as a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).
I also tried adding the color-names as ListViewItems (so i could control their ForeColor), but the DataGridViewComboBoxCells didn't show the colored text - instead, they listed the color-names as ListViewItems (i.e. they showed a list of: "ListViewItem: {Red}", and so on).

Is it possible to add the ComboBoxes to the DataGridView in a way that I can still reference them as regular ComboBoxes? If not, then how do I do the mentioned in the first paragraph?

Comment: Maybe like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007745/show-list-of-colors-in-combobox-color-picker

Comment: The [answer of TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36339884/880990) to the question [Using a custom UserControl as a Column in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36335494/880990) could help you realize such a thing. There seems to be no easy solution, so.